# IE performance slow with jquery and memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks

Hi I have the following code.

```
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
<input id="input3" type="text">
// ... so on up to 12.
```

my code

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function ($) {
   var i, id;
   for (i = 1; i != 13; ++i) {
        id = "input" + i;
        $(myFunc).on("change", function() {
             this.value += " tab";
        });
   }
);
```

I am getting memory leak on input1, input2 ... according to drip.

How can i solve this.

Comment: can you please tell us where your variable `myFunc` comes from and what does it contain?

Comment: probably you meant `id` instead of myFunc.. just a typo? maybe, when you change the value via `this.value += "tab";`, IE fires the change event again thus causing an infinite loop.. but thats just a wild guess

Comment: @Chips_100 changing the value with javascript does not automatically trigger native events, there is no infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to run this 12 times, I would do (notice the less than vs not-equal operation):

```
for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i) {
```

Also, where is myFunc defined?  Maybe you're trying to do:

```
$(id).on("change", function() {
         this.value += " tab";
});
```

One other thing, and I don't know if this is still an issue, in some browsers, jQuery use to have a problem setting a value on an input where there was no value attribute define.

```
<input id="input1" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? doing a loop to set id to input1-12, but your on.('change') eventlistener doesn't even use the 'id' variable?

Are you trying to listen for change on any of your inputs and add " tab" to it when it changes? If so

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
     $(this).attr('value') += " tab";
});
```

will suffice.

Comment: hmm is this faster than searching tweleve time by id? performance wise. i have about 10000 dom elements.

Comment: Wrap your twelve inputs in a container div, and call the change function like this: $('containerdiv').on('change', 'input', function() { blablabla });

Comment: sorry can't. The 12 inputs are spread out. They are spread out across tabs, select options, checkboxes and other inputs. Basically it is really slow on IE and sometimes it takes 20 seconds to process the page (javascript wise and drip would show memory leak with object register by jquery).